# Do production compilers use parser generators?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, parser-generator

I've heard that "real compiler writers" roll their own handmade parser rather than using parser generators.  I've also heard that parser generators don't cut it for real-world languages.  Supposedly, there are many special cases that are difficult to implement using a parser generator.  I have my doubts about this:

1. Theoretically, a GLR parser generator should be able to handle most programming language designs (except maybe C++...)
2. I know of at least one production language that uses a parser generator: Ruby [1].
3. When I took my compilers class in school, we used a parser generator.

So my question: Is it reasonable to write a production compiler using a parser generator, or is using a parser generator considered a poor design decision by the compiler community?

[1] https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/parse.y

Comment: real programmers use bread boards.

Comment: I thought they used butterflies http://xkcd.com/378/

Comment: GLR parsers handle C++ just fine. Our tools use GLR to parse a variety of C++ dialects, and some other 30 languages. (See my bio for "our tools").

Comment: It's not really that difficult to write all parser rules for C++, even C++0x, and use parser generator, but you will never get the performance of handcrafted parser, even if you use best C++ parser generators. And performance in parsing C++ is extremely important.

Comment: @Gene Why is it that a handcrafted parser will beat a C++ parser generator?  Considering that writing a hand-crafted parser is a lot of code, isn't it possible that the hand-crafted parser could be much slower?

Comment: @Matt: done both writing parsers by hand, writing parser generators and writing rules for them. Parser generators practically always create suboptimal code, it's not difficult to do better by hand, but since writing rules for parser generator is so much easier and faster I would do it first before resorting to hand-written parser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For what it's worth, GCC used a parser generator pre-4.0 I believe, then switched to a hand written recursive descent parser because it was easier to maintain and extend.

Parser generators DO "cut it" for "real" languages, but the amount of work to transform your grammar into something workable grows exponentially.

Edit: link to the GCC document detailing the change with reasons and benefits vs cost analysis: http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/New_C_Parser.

Answer (score 1):

I worked for a company for a few years where we were more or less writing compilers. We weren't concerned much with performance; just reducing the amount of work/maintenance. We used a combination of generated parsers + handwritten code to achieve this. The ideal balance is to automate the easy, repetitive parts with the parser generator and then tackle the hard stuff in custom functions.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a combination of both methods, is used, like generating code with a parser, and later, modifying "by hand" that code.

Other way is that some scanner (lexer) and parser tools allow them to add custom code, additional to the grammar rules, called "semantic actions". A good example of this case, is that, a parser detects generic identifiers, and some custom code, transform some specific identifiers into keywords.

EDIT:
add "semantic actions"

Answer (score 0):

Notably CPython uses a parser generator:

- [Python Documentation: Guide to the parser](https://devguide.python.org/internals/parser/)
- [PEP 617: New PEG parser for CPython](https://peps.python.org/pep-0617/)

Presumably also to have a cleaner represenation of the language, although I have not seen an explicit rationale for why a parse generator instead of a hand-written one.